# .htaccess rewrite from sub directory to top level domain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a domain set up as shop.mydomain.com - however the domain name is changing to just www.mydomain.com

So, all traffic that comes in for shop.mydomain.com, needs to redirect to www.mydomain.com

E.g. shop.mydomain.com/product001.html need to redirect to www.mydomain.com/product001.html

Is this possible with a rewrite rule? All site URLs remain the same, but they now reside on www.mydomain.com as opposed to shop.mydomain.com

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I was trying: 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://shop.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mydomain.com[L] ... but it falls over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this [article](http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```